# Eagle digital GND polygon does not fill

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I am working on a volume control board using PGA2311 and this IC needs two GNDS - analog and digital. Why does the DGND polygon not fill? The image below shows the problem:

[image: Polygon settings]

Now I have similar problem, the polygon won't fill, any ideas? It is ANALOG +5V polygon.[image]

Comment: Did you make sure the fill is on the same net as the DGnd? Because it might not have the same name.

Comment: I did, I highlight DGND pin on IC and polygon gets highlighted, just won fill!

Comment: Maybe its a problem with your enclosing Dimension layer? From your picture, its not entirely clear where the outline is. Polygons outside of dimension won't fill.

Comment: Here are two screenshots, first for Polygon Highlight (IC's pin DGND is connected to polygon) and the second one represents polygon info.[PolygonInfo](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/838/a36o.png/) and [HighlightedPolygon](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/526/oe2b.png/)

Comment: What Eagle version? Maybe you can you provide a link to the board file? (btw: Setting isolate to 0 is uncommon. You can see it causing some "artifacts" on the filled polygon)

Comment: Eagle version is 6.3.0 / Windows. I will change isolate from 0, but, I do not know, what Isolate attribute means.

Comment: Try running the ratsnest tool?  For some reason this seems to be the trigger for updating of polygon fills.

Comment: I did run ratsnet tool, no effect ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the clearance area around your pads, the problem is most likely the pad-to-wire clearance setting in your design rules. If the clearance (minimum distance) is set too high, the polygon place can't connect to the respective PIN. As a result, the polygon won't fill at all.

I can reproduce your problem just fine setting the highlighted value to something like 80 mil.

[image: design rules]

This polygon fills fine using a pad-to-wire clearance of 8 mil, but not 80 mil.

[image]

If that does not solve the problem, it may also be a restriction that you defined in your NET classes. So check those too.

EDIT:
Another idea to narrow down the problem: Got to the polygon settings and check the "Orphans" setting. This will instruct eagle to create polygons, even if there is no way to connected them. If this helps, its definitely the problem that your PAD can't be connected due to some limiting rule.

EDIT2:
As stated in the comments, orphaned polygons will be processed. So it comes down to one of these:

- the wire width **of the polygon** is set too high
- at least one of the relevant clearance values in the design rules is to large
- at least one of the relevant clearance values in the net class specifications is to large

Comment: Setting clearance also does not help and in schematics I've setup both AGND and DGND as GROUND Net class.

Comment: Check that <Options -> Settings -> Misc: "ratsnest calculates polygons"> is selected. If you rip-up the "functioning" polygon and select ratsnest, will it properly fill again?

Comment: That option is selected/turned ON.

Comment: Wow, trick with "Orphans" did the job, polygon fills now! But why DGND from IC's pin is not connected to polygon, nevertheless if I click with "Show" on GND, both pin and polygon get highlighted?

Comment: Glad to hear that, but you still have to fix it, since the GND polygon is obviously useless without connection.

Comment: I do not know what you mean with EDIT!

Comment: Please post an image of your net class configuration and state what net class the pad above DGND is assigned to.

Comment: So, user Rev1.0 helped me solve my problem: In Net Classes, I hade too wide signal class declaration and I have narrowed down all net classes width to 16 mils and then it worked! The polygon fills without "Orphan" selected!